# Is there an elegant way to change what methods/variables an object of a class can use based on the constructor used to create this object?

Tags: java, constructor, visibility

So for example, when the object is constructed with lets say a constructor without arguments, this object is able/"allowed" to use a certain subset of the methods defined in the class, and when the object is created with a different constructor (for example with arguments) it is able/"allowed" to use a different subset of the methods defined in the class.

**These are the conceptual solutions that spring to mind:**

1. Use reflection in the constructors to modify the visibility/accessibility of its class methods. (Problem with this is *EURGH... reflection*)
2. Set boolean flags like `isAllowedToUseMethodA` in the constructor to identify which methods the object will be allowed to use. (Problem with this is the overhead the boolean checks will impose and also methods which are flagged as inaccessible will still be visible to the object and can be attempted to execute)

The obvious *elephant in the room* answer to this is **"Make 2 different classes."** and I understand that, I'm just curious is there an elegant way to do this if I want to do this in a single class?

Comment: The only wise answer is to do what the elephant is telling you. Perhaps the "composite pattern" is the only exception to this.

Comment: This is _inherently_ non-elegant. Obviously, if you want to use a set of methods instead of another, then the two classes are not the same. At most, they can share a parent. You have to make 2 different classes, maybe extracting a common interface or abstract base if it is the case.

Comment: If you use the first 2 methods, your design will be bad and could break.

Comment: use decorator pattern. Unfortunaetly that would be 2+ classes

Comment: Here comments provide better answers than the answers posted.

Answer (score 0):

Both options 1 and 2 have a multitude of problems, however fortunately there is a simple and reasonably elegant way to do exactly what you want:

Use inheritance.

Define different versions of the object all inheriting off a common (potentially abstract) core.

Then have factory methods that construct the correct version of each one depending on which factory method you call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually use a different subset of methods, but you can kind of 'switch' by means of the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

E.g. for your constructors you set different strategies:

```
public class XXX() {
    method1Strategy = new method1Strategy1();
    method2Strategy = new method2Strategy1();
}

public class XXX( ... ) {
    method1Strategy = new method1Strategy2();
    method2Strategy = new method2Strategy2();
}
```

And in your methods you execute the concrete strategy:

```
public Object method1(...) {
   return method1Strategy.execute(...)
}

public Object method2(...) {
   return method2Strategy.execute(...)
}
```